# How to save my files from initramfs for Ubuntu 22.04, which is unable to boot?

Tags: ubuntu, files, initramfs

My Ubuntu got broken because UUID isn't correct, and I try all the ways but not fix it, so I decided to reinstall Ubuntu again. However, I **need the old files in Ubuntu**, is there any way for me to copy it without booting Ubuntu, namely, can I copy my files from initramfs? Thanks!

Comment: initramfs should not be used in that case. Your best shot is using systemrescueCD or GRML type linux on USB stick so you can mount your old disk and any network drive to backup.